# Loading a file using rootBundle

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to load a string from a file. The following code always returns null:

```
static String  l( String name ) {

    String contents;

    rootBundle
     .loadString( 'i10n/de.yaml' )
     .then( (String r)  { contents = 'found'; print( 'then()' ); })
     .catchError( (e) { contents =  '@Error@'; print( 'catchError()' );  })
     .whenComplete(() { contents = 'dd'; print( 'whenComplete()' );  })
     ;

    print( 'after' );

    if ( null == contents ) {
      return '@null@';
    }

    String doc = loadYaml( contents );

    return doc;

  }
```

I have added this to the flutter: section in pupspec.yaml section:

```
  assets:
    - i10n/de.yaml
    - i10n/en.yaml
```

The file i10n/de.yaml exists.

I'm aware, that rootBundle.loadString() is async. Therefore I appended the then() call - assuming that

```
(String r)  { contents = 'found'; }
```

only gets executed if the Future returned by rootBundle.loadString() is able to return a value.

Actually, the method always returns '@null@'. Therefore, I added the print() statements, which output this:

```
I/flutter (22382): after
I/flutter (22382): then()
I/flutter (22382): whenComplete()
```

OK, obviously the future of loadString() executes later than the final print() statement.

**Q: But how do I force the future to execute, so that I may retrieve its value?**

**In other words: How do I wrap some async stuff in certain code to retrieve its value immediately?**

PS: First day of flutter/dart. Probably a trivial question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.then()` is getting executed, but *after* the rest of the body. As you mention `loadString()` returns a Future, so completes in the future. To wait for a Future to complete use `await`. (Note that when you mark the function as async, the function must now return a Future itself - as it has to wait for loadString to complete in the future, so it itself has to complete in the future...) When you call `l('something')` you will have to await the result.

```
Future<String> l(String name) async {
  try {
    String contents = await rootBundle.loadString('i10n/de.yaml');

    return contents == null ? '@null@' : loadYaml(contents);
  } catch (e) {
    return 'oops $e';
  }
}
```

It's no big deal that lots of your utility functions become `async` as a result of having to wait for things (there's a lot of waiting - for files to read, http requests to complete, etc). You'll eventually end up at the top with something like (call this from `initState`)

```
refresh(String s) {
  l(s).then((r) {
    setState(() {
      i18nStuff = r;
    });
  });
}
```

to set the state of your Widget when the i18nStuff is ready, and a Widget that has this in its build to switch between a dummy ui for the few milliseconds until it's ready, and then the real UI.

```
Widget build() {
  if (i18nStuff == null) {
    return new Container();
  }

  return new Column(
      // build the real UI here
      );
}
```

Comment: Thx! And there is no way to wait for completion of the future at a certain point of code?

Comment: OK, I see. The code should load localized strings. And I need them to show the first widget. Should I then load the resources asynchronously and put the creation of the app / widget in a top level then() part?

Comment: You could make `main()` async and load stuff there, but better, see edited answer